# How to build MathML expression from infix notation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, client, mathml

I'm trying to understand whether there is an elegant way to convert
(in client side)
From "infix notation" to MathML expression
for example : from 1+2 to:
[the MathML expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBbMB.png)

Many thanks

Comment: What is "infix notation"? You might want to check out [asciimath](http://asciimath.org/).

Comment: infix notation is the conventional way to Display mathematical expression : "1+2"  contrast to postfix expression "1 2 +". Anyway i found a solution.. i use Latex. Thanks!